# HTML Input textbox required still showing error message for data binded automatically

Tags: html, angular

I have a HTML textbox having required attribute enabled on it.

Validation is working fine except in one scenario.

When data is binded dynamically, then error message still getting displayed. But if I do any key press on textbox then error message disappears.

How to resolve issue.

**Update:**

I'm using below code

```
<input type="text" aria-label="text" [disabled]="isDisable"                                                        
#TEXTVALUE="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'invalid-data': TEXTVALUE.invalid && userForm.submitted, 'valid-data': TEXTVALUE.valid && userForm.submitted}"   [ngModel]="customernamevalue" name="customername"  id="custname"
 [required]= "true">

 <div  style="float:left;" 
*ngIf="TEXTVALUE.invalid && (TEXTVALUE.dirty || TEXTVALUE.touched)">
 <span style="color: red;"> Name is mandatory field.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried custom validation using javascript?

Comment: Show us some code ?

Comment: I have used angular ngForm for validation

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: code has been updated in question.kindly suggest.

Comment: check the DOM of the input and see which class is getting applied on it